# Stream reset exception while using okhttp3 for sending audio data to Amazon Alexa

Tags: android, okhttp, alexa-skills-kit

On trying to send the audio request to Alexa, this error is occurring many times. Using the library for Alexa in github : **https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid**

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: CANCEL
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.checkOutNotClosed(Http2Stream.java:567)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.emitFrame(Http2Stream.java:501)
at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.write(Http2Stream.java:481)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:171)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:85)
at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:171)
at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:113)
at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:59)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
at com.willblaschko.android.alexa.AlexaManager$AsyncEventHandler.success(AlexaManager.java:614)
at com.willblaschko.android.alexa.AlexaManager$AsyncEventHandler.success(AlexaManager.java:594)
at com.willblaschko.android.alexa.interfaces.speechrecognizer.SpeechSendAudio.sendAudio(SpeechSendAudio.java:54)
at com.willblaschko.android.alexa.AlexaManager$5$1$1.doInBackground(AlexaManager.java:349)
at com.willblaschko.android.alexa.AlexaManager$5$1$1.doInBackground(AlexaManager.java:345)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I found the reason is that sink.write()/writeTo() is not stopped since AVS has not the ability to detect a pause/silence from voice, it looks like fromwillblaschko/AlexaAndroid using **recorder.isPausing()** to stop  writeTo()/sink.write().hope it help you.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you are saying, could you please correct it.

Comment: Sorry，My meaning is maybe the reason of question is that 'writeTo()' have no be stop.Willblaschko using ' recorder.isPausing()' jump out of the loop.

Comment: I fixed the stream reset issue by restarting the down channel service every time I launch the application. And AVS has the ability to detect the end of the speech (silence), we can use **stopCapture** directive to stop the recording.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the StreamResetException issue by restarting the down channel service every time when I launch the application.

According to Amazon the stream should reset after completion of the current session.